# Create nested loop to segment data in dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to create a nested loop to segment data in a dataframe into a series of smaller tables using the subset() function.

The data is segmented geographically by state, then into categories for each state, which then contains sales figures over time. The work has traditionally been done just using Excel, but the data itself is pretty large, with around 10-12,000 points of data, and the structure of the data constantly changes, with new categories being added, removed or renamed, hence why I want to automate the process in R rather than manually rebuild reports in Excel.

The problem is I can't get the second loop to work properly. When I run the code, the data is subset into the first set of two tables which contain the correct observations, but the second set of tables in the second loop contain the correct number of tables, but with no observations. There is obviously something wrong in the second assign function that I can't work out.

EDITED TO ADD:

The desired output from this will go toward building a report with a series of printed out tables. The idea behind it is the initial data comes in a single, massive table stored as a csv or Excel file, but different people are interested in different parts of the data, which means it has to be separated into various components, each then printed out, aggregated and summarised in various ways. So the idea is to take the large dataset, then break it down into pieces that can be worked on individually. Different versions of the report will have different internal structures with different numbers of categories, which is why I wanted to be able to dynamically create the tables via a loop, so that one piece of code can manage differing data structures.

It probably isn't the ideal way to approach things, but such is the way some managers insist on working.

```
    library(dplyr)

    # Create trial data

    by_state <- c("state1", "state1", "state1", "state1", "state1",  
   "state1", "state1", "state1", "state1", "state2", "state2", "state2",  
   "state2", "state2", "state2", "state2", "state2", "state2")
    by_category <- c("cat1", "cat1","cat1", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2",  
   "cat3", "cat3", "cat3", "cat1", "cat1","cat1", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2",  
   "cat3", "cat3", "cat3")
    y2001 <- runif(18, 1, 100) %>%
    round(digits = 0)
    y2002 <- runif(18, 1, 100) %>%
      round(digits = 0)
    y2003 <- runif(18, 1, 100) %>%
      round(digits = 0)

    df <- data.frame(by_state, by_category, y2001, y2002, y2003)

    # Create two lists for each loop

    sec1 <- data.frame(unique(df$by_state))
    sec2 <- data.frame(unique(df$by_category))

    # Create loop to segment data 

    for (c in 1:nrow(sec1)) {
      for (d in 1:nrow(sec2)) {
        assign(paste0("table", c),
               subset(df, df$by_state == paste0(sec1[c,])))
        assign(paste0("table", c, d),
               subset(get(paste0("table", c)), paste0("table", c,  
    "$by_category") == paste0(sec2[d,])))
      }
    }
```

Comment: There is a function for that in base R, it is called `split`. Also, never use `assign` to store something in a dynamically named variable, you should use a (named) list instead. You can use nested lists to store nested data structures.

Comment: What is your expected output? I'll go along with the idea of not needing to build independent tables

Comment: The use case you describe (building a report containing the various tables) is actually what I had in mind as a counter-example where splitting the data is useful. You _could_ still use `group_by`, in particular in conjunction with `tidyr::nest`, but splitting definitely makes sense in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, I'll just point out that there is probably no need to split your data in many small data.frames. You can probably do whatever you are trying to do simply using `group_by(state, category)`.

That being said, this is how you'd split your data by state: using the `split` function provided by base R.

```r
library("dplyr")
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df <- data.frame(
  state = c("state1", "state1", "state1", "state1", "state1",  
            "state1", "state1", "state1", "state1", "state2", "state2", "state2",  
            "state2", "state2", "state2", "state2", "state2", "state2"),
  category = c("cat1", "cat1","cat1", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2",  
               "cat3", "cat3", "cat3", "cat1", "cat1","cat1", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2",  
               "cat3", "cat3", "cat3"),
  y2001 = runif(18, 1, 100) %>%
    round(digits = 0),
  y2002 = runif(18, 1, 100) %>%
    round(digits = 0),
  y2003 = runif(18, 1, 100) %>%
    round(digits = 0)
)

# This creates a named list of sub data.frames
df_by_state <- split(df, df$state)
# 2 named elements
names(df_by_state)
#> [1] "state1" "state2"
# You can access them by indexing using the name
df_by_state$state1
#>    state category y2001 y2002 y2003
#> 1 state1     cat1    18    95    90
#> 2 state1     cat1    69    15    50
#> 3 state1     cat1    90    62    68
#> 4 state1     cat2    81    29    55
#> 5 state1     cat2    94     9    99
#> 6 state1     cat2    42    30    66
#> 7 state1     cat3    79     7    38
#> 8 state1     cat3     6    95    95
#> 9 state1     cat3    95     4    87
# Or the index
df_by_state[[1]]
#>    state category y2001 y2002 y2003
#> 1 state1     cat1    18    95    90
#> 2 state1     cat1    69    15    50
#> 3 state1     cat1    90    62    68
#> 4 state1     cat2    81    29    55
#> 5 state1     cat2    94     9    99
#> 6 state1     cat2    42    30    66
#> 7 state1     cat3    79     7    38
#> 8 state1     cat3     6    95    95
#> 9 state1     cat3    95     4    87

# This splits every element of df_by_state by category
# Creating a list of lists
df_by_state_cat <- purrr::map(df_by_state, ~ split(., .$category))
# You can access your data.frames like so
df_by_state_cat$state2$cat2
#>     state category y2001 y2002 y2003
#> 13 state2     cat2    87    42    95
#> 14 state2     cat2    97    97    29
#> 15 state2     cat2    40    74    47


# Alternatively, you can directly split df by both state and category
# You need to create a combined state_cat variable:
df_by_state_cat2 <- split(df, paste(df$state, df$category, sep = "_"))
# You get an element for each state_cat combination
names(df_by_state_cat2)
#> [1] "state1_cat1" "state1_cat2" "state1_cat3" "state2_cat1" "state2_cat2"
#> [6] "state2_cat3"
# The list is flat and not nested, you can access elements like this:
df_by_state_cat2$state2_cat2
#>     state category y2001 y2002 y2003
#> 13 state2     cat2    87    42    95
#> 14 state2     cat2    97    97    29
#> 15 state2     cat2    40    74    47
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

There is no need to use a loop but, if you had to, this is how you could improve your code:

- Don't define `sec1` and `sec2` as data.frames when they can just be vectors. You can loop on the values directly instead of the indices.
- Assign the values in a named list (that you initialised before)
- Use meaningful variable names

```r
by_state <- list()
by_state_cat <- list()

for (sta in unique(df$state)) {
  for (cat in unique(df$category)) {
    by_state[[sta]] <- filter(df, state == sta)
    by_state_cat[[paste(sta, cat, sep = "_")]] <- 
      filter(by_state[[sta]], category == cat)
  }
}
```

You'll see it is equivalent to the code using `split`, except longer and environment-polluting (since `sta` and `cat` still exist after the loop).

Answer (score 2):

A simple change in your second assign statement will see the desired results:

```
   assign(paste0("table", c, d),
           subset(get(paste0("table", c)), get(paste0("table", c))$by_category == paste0(sec2[d,])))
  }
```

Needed a `get()` around the second reference to table above, so you can compare the values.

Antoine's example utilising lists, however, would be the more appropriate approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my list solution:

```
library(dplyr)

# Create trial data

by_state <- c("state1", "state1", "state1", "state1", "state1",  
              "state1", "state1", "state1", "state1", "state2", "state2", "state2",  
              "state2", "state2", "state2", "state2", "state2", "state2")
by_category <- c("cat1", "cat1","cat1", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2",  
                 "cat3", "cat3", "cat3", "cat1", "cat1","cat1", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2",  
                 "cat3", "cat3", "cat3")
y2001 <- runif(18, 1, 100) %>%
        round(digits = 0)
y2002 <- runif(18, 1, 100) %>%
        round(digits = 0)
y2003 <- runif(18, 1, 100) %>%
        round(digits = 0)

df <- data.frame(by_state, by_category, y2001, y2002, y2003)

# Create two lists for each loop

sec1 <- data.frame(unique(df$by_state))
sec2 <- data.frame(unique(df$by_category))

# creating list by state

list_by_state <- list()
for(i in 1:nrow(sec1)){
        name <- paste('table',paste0(sec1[i,]),sep='_')
        tmp <- subset(df, df$by_state == paste0(sec1[i,]))
        list_by_state[[name]] <- tmp
}

# creating list by state and category

list_bystate_category <- list()
for(i in 1:nrow(sec1)){
        for (j in 1:nrow(sec2)){
                name <- paste('table',paste0(sec1[i,]),paste0(sec2[j,]),sep='_')
                tmp <- filter(df, df$by_state == paste0(sec1[i,]), df$by_category == paste0(sec2[j,]))
                list_bystate_category[[name]] <- tmp
        }
}
```